# Prepare Gantt Graph using Microsoft Access 2007

Tags: microsoft-access, gantt

I would like to prepare a Gantt graph using Microsoft Access 2007.
I thought about using "Pivot Charts" but any other idea would be fine.
I have here a picture of what I have in mind, done with Excel 2007:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Courtesy of Google and [here](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=108369). It provides a worked example that is easy to edit and extend.

Comment: Hello there!
Thanks for helping...
I've tried that sample but it's graphically not pleasing...
You have hints about how making it similar to the picture I've posted?
Thanks :)